# Give led a random color

Tags: arduino

Is it possible to assign a random color to a led?
It's not a problem if two or more leds have the same color.

I tried something like this:
trying to assing a color to a number, and giving the led a random number.
The code doesn't validate, it's not possible to combine an int with a random number (at least not the way I tried)

The CRGB:: after the randNumber is part of the FastLED lib for giving the led a color. Within Fastled you can you names for the colors.

```
#include "FastLED.h"
#define NUM_LEDS 10

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

#define DATA_PIN 2

long randNumber;
long randNumber0 = CRGB::Red;
long randNumber1 = CRGB::White;
long randNumber2 = CRGB::Blue;
long randNumber3 = CRGB::Red;
long randNumber4 = CRGB::White;
long randNumber5 = CRGB::Blue;
long randNumber6 = CRGB::Red;
long randNumber7 = CRGB::White;
long randNumber8 = CRGB::Blue;
long randNumber9 = CRGB::Red;

#define INTERVAL_MESSAGE1 5000

unsigned long time_1 = 0;

void setup() {
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, DATA_PIN, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  if (millis() >= time_1 + INTERVAL_MESSAGE1) {
    time_1 += INTERVAL_MESSAGE1;
    leds[0] =  randNumber.random(0,9);
    leds[1] =  randNumber.random(0,9);
    leds[2] =  randNumber.random(0,9);
    leds[3] =  randNumber.random(0,9);
    leds[4] =  randNumber.random(0,9);
    leds[5] =  randNumber.random(0,9);
    leds[6] =  randNumber.random(0,9);
    leds[7] =  randNumber.random(0,9);
    leds[8] =  randNumber.random(0,9);
    leds[9] =  randNumber.random(0,9);
    FastLED.show(55);
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is using array for it and use random for selecting index in it. Btw, the language is C++, so you can check some tutorial.

```
#include "FastLED.h"
#define NUM_LEDS 10

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

#define DATA_PIN 2

long randNumber[10] = {
  CRGB::Red,
  CRGB::White,
  CRGB::Blue,
  CRGB::Red,
  CRGB::White,
  CRGB::Blue,
  CRGB::Red,
  CRGB::White,
  CRGB::Blue,
  CRGB::Red
};

#define INTERVAL_MESSAGE1 5000

unsigned long time_1 = 0;

void setup() {
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, DATA_PIN, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  if (millis() >= time_1 + INTERVAL_MESSAGE1) {
    time_1 += INTERVAL_MESSAGE1;

    for (auto & led : leds) {
      led = randNumber[random(0,10)];
    }
    
    FastLED.show(55);
  }
}
```